# Angular Material: How to format datepicker day label?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

Is it possible to change the day labels from 2 characters to 3?

### From:

[image]

### To:

[image]

I couldn't find any reference to that in the docs.

Comment: Noam Steiner, could you please share your knowledge about how you done calendar view with dots in day view?!

Comment: Read about `dateClass: MatCalendarCellCssClasses` of `mat-calendar`. you can define css classes for specific dates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Angular Material Datepicker weekday headers can be customized by extending the `MomentDateAdapter`.

```js
@Injectable()
class CustomDateAdapter extends MomentDateAdapter {
  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow') {
    return ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  }
}
```

See [**Stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-day-of-week-names?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

#### References

This answer was originally provided by [Andrew Seguin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7327910/andrew-seguin)  in response to [Angular Components issue #16240](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16240).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Similar solution, here is how you can implement it.

Create a custom-date-adapter.ts in the same component folder, where the Calendar is.
The contents of the file will be -

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from "@angular/material/core";

export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
getDayOfWeekNames(style): string[] {

    const SHORT_NAMES = ['Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

    return SHORT_NAMES;
  }
}
```

In your component.ts file make followng changes -

```
import { CustomDateAdapter } from './custom-date-adapter';
```

and then in the @Component

```
 providers: [
         {
           provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter
         },
            ],
```

This should solve your issue.